# is it best way to include javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

```
// Cookies code     
$.getScript("/a/js/cookie.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
    // set cookies
    $.cookie('name','value');
}).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    console.log('Failed.');
});
//---------------------------------------------------
// Collapse code    
$.getScript("/a/js/collapse.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
    //toggle arrow
    $('.accordion-toggle').click(function (e) {
       $( this ).find( 'li.arrow' ).toggleClass('down-arrow up-arrow', 200);
       $('.accordion-toggle').not( this ).find( 'li.arrow' ).removeClass('up-arrow');
    });
});
```

Is that good way to include all the js files needed for the web page, does it have any disadvantages or advantages

Thanks

Comment: Consider using a script loader like HeadJS or yepnope.

Comment: In particular, make sure you don't run the same script twice.  You can use an associative array of cached promises.

Comment: https://github.com/SLaks/Glisten/blob/gh-pages/Javascript/providers.js#L17-L25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader that will help you.

Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will improve the speed and quality of your code.
It also lets you declare file dependencies.

[Requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org/)